# Running Specflow scenarios in parallel

Tags: nunit, specflow

I am working with the following

Specflow - 2.2.1
nUnit - 3.9.0

And i was hoping its possible to allow 2 scenarios within the same feature to run in parallel. The reason for this is to speed up the test suite.

The aim would be to get a few tests (2-3) running in parallel within the same feature, rather than running sequentially.

Does anyone know how this is possible?

I have added this to my assembly -

[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children)]

but i am now seeing the following errors

```
An item with the same key has already been added.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: I had similar error when i was trying to run test in parallel and trying to preserve values in dictionary. Are you using Scenario or Feature context in your test?

Comment: I am not, i have removed these when i got them to run in parallel on a feature level. But now getting this error when they run in parallel on a scenario level. I have a feeling its not creating separate threads for each test and therefore tests are running into on another.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am running into this problem as well

Comment: @st0ve Still working on it, the above is an issue about a Key is a specflow error message. It cannot handle parallel jobs at a child level. Got around it for now by splitting up the features a little more as they run in parallel without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario level parallelism is not supported by SpecFlow yet.
You can read in their [docs](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Execution/Parallel-Execution.html) they ONLY allow you to use:

```
[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
```

There is an open ticket that describes all the issues why this is not supported yet and ways to solve it - https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/1535

Please note that even though that NUnit added support for [Instance-per-test-case feature](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2574) in the new version(3.13) it doesn't solve the problem (I tried it with [LifeCycle.InstancePerTestCase](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/fixturelifecycle.html) and still got some errors).

There is an open issue in SpecFlow repo for this problem: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/894